# How should I UpdateOne multiple values with a form?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ejs

This is where I want to try to edit every single value, using a single bottom to send all the data.

[image]ack.imgur.com/S5jg1.png

This is my form. My idea was to put a hidden input value that every document has, DescripcionBusqueda.

```
<form
  action="/EdicionMaterialesPost"
  method="POST"
  enctype="multipart/form-data"
>
  <% for (var a = 0; a < materiales.length; a++) { %>
  <tr>
    <th>
      <%=materiales[a].Descripcion%>
      <input
        type="text"
        class="form-control"
        placeholder="Descripcion"
        id="Descripcion"
        name="Descripcion"
      />
      <input
        type="hidden"
        class="form-control"
        id="DescripcionBusqueda"
        name="DescripcionBusqueda"
        value="<%=materiales[a].Descripcion%>"
      />
    </th>
    <th>
      <%=materiales[a].Codigo%>
      <input
        type="text"
        class="form-control"
        placeholder="Codigo"
        id="Codigo"
        name="Codigo"
      />
    </th>
    <th>
      <%=materiales[a].Unidad%>
      <input
        type="text"
        class="form-control"
        placeholder="Unidad"
        id="Unidad"
        name="Unidad"
      />
    </th>
    <th>
      <%=materiales[a].PrecioUnitario%>
      <input
        type="number"
        class="form-control"
        placeholder="PrecioUnitario"
        id="PrecioUnitario"
        name="PrecioUnitario"
      />
    </th>
    <th>
      <%=materiales[a].Familia%>
      <input
        type="text"
        class="form-control"
        placeholder="Familia"
        id="Familia"
        name="Familia"
      />
    </th>
    <th>
      <%=materiales[a].SubFam%>
      <input
        type="text"
        class="form-control"
        placeholder="SubFam"
        id="SubFam"
        name="SubFam"
      />
    </th>
  </tr>
  <% } %>
  <button type="submit" id="sendMessageButton">Guardar Cambios</button>
</form>
```

And here is where I try to UpdateOne, I was thinking about using a for "With the "descriptionBusqueda" as index 0, will only UpdateOne documents (req.body.Myinputname) with index 0". And input without value won't be changed... but everything becomes chaos.

Can I have some help with my logic?

```
const material = require('../models/materiales.js');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = async (req, res) => {
  for (i = 0; i < req.body.DescripcionBusqueda.length; i++) {
    await material.updateOne(
      { Descripcion: req.body.DescripcionBusqueda[i] },
      {
        $set: {
          Descripcion: req.body.Descripcion[i],
          Codigo: req.body.Codigo[i],
          Unidad: req.body.Unidad[i],
          PrecioUnitario: req.body.PrecioUnitario[i],
          Familia: req.body.Familia[i],
          SubFam: req.body.SubFam[i],
        },
      },
      { upsert: false }
    );
  }

  res.redirect('/');
};
```

Example of my doc

```
_id ObjectoId('6396d947f3a8a9fa8c3c7727')
Descripcion:"Angulo 1/8" x 1 1/4" de 6.10 mts. (1.50 kg/mt)"
Codigo:"AA-03"
Unidad:"Pza."
PrecioUnitario:260.84
Familia:"Aceros"
SubFam:"Angulos"
__v:0
```

Comment: Welcome!   Could you show us an example of the doc (or docs) before the update and what you want to see after the update?

Comment: Thank you, the image above is the doc before an update, and what I would like to see, for example, If I change "PrecioUnitario" -> 260.84 in his input, just change that value with the sent form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to check the form for changed data *and* programmatically construct the `$set` component of the update.  Your logic with the iteration is correct; there is no way (with `update()`) to update a bunch of different docs in MongoDB with different variations of `$set` in one call.   Your logic will end up something like the following.   If you don't have marker vars like `DescripcionCHANGED` that is OK; you will just have to compare before-and-after versions using your `hidden` vars.

```js
    for(i=0; i<req.body.DescripcionBusqueda.length;i++){
        var sdoc = {};
        if(req.body.DescripcionCHANGED[i]) {
          sdoc['Descripcion'] = req.body.Descripcion[i]
        }
        if(req.body.CodigoCHANGED[i]) {
          sdoc['Codigo'] = req.body.Codigo[i]
        }
        if(req.body.UnidadCHANGED[i]) {
          sdoc['Unidad'] = req.body.Unidad[i]
        }
        //  etc. etc.....

        material.updateOne(
                {Descripcion:req.body.DescripcionBusqueda[i]},
                {$set: sdoc},
                { upsert: false });
    }
```